# Quickest way to save massive amount of lines to text file in c#

Tags: c#, save

Im currently programming a program which needs to save multiple megabytes worth of data to text files.

that data is saved inside a string
    < list >

my current code (allusernames is the list variable name)

```
      string alltoappend = "";
        string speichern = "C:\\Users\\" + Environment.UserName + "\\Desktop\\scraped.txt";
        progressBarSetValue(progressBar1, 100);
        MessageBox.Show("Done scraping!\nNow saving all the usernames to:\n" + speichern + "\nThis might take a while");
        foreach (string linelist in allusernames)
        {

            alltoappend = alltoappend + "\n" + linelist;
        }

        File.AppendAllText(speichern, alltoappend, Encoding.UTF8);



        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(speichern);
        allusernames.Clear();
```

it can take multiple minutes to save a megabyte of data which is unnesecary..

is there a quicker way of doing this? i heard some .join() suggestions from people but i do not know how to use that.

help very appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string line in allusernames)
{
    sb.AppendLine(line);
}
string result = sb.ToString();
```

Also you can directly write to file:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(filename))
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        foreach (string line in allusernames)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

And don't use path as you are.

Wrong:

```
string speichern = "C:\\Users\\" + Environment.UserName + "\\Desktop\\scraped.txt";
```

Right:

```
string speichern = Path.Combine("C:\\Users", Environment.UserName , "Desktop\\scraped.txt");
```

The best:

```
string speichern = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "scraped.txt");
```

Comment: then use it `sb.ToString();` - as string

Comment: what is the advantage? also where is the output directory?

Comment: Rest of the code is same, but the concatention method is faster. StringBuilder does not create unneccessary objects, so it is faster to join more than approx. 1000 strings

Comment: Strings are immutable, meaning they cannot be changed. So everyone of your string concatenations creates a new (longer) string, copy the old on into it, writes a name at the end, and deletes the old one. That is horribly inefficient, as the first name gets written and deleted for every name.

Comment: ah so at the end i append the sb object? it the ToString() version of it ? :)

Comment: Yes.It should be faster though to write the names directly to the disc, one by one, instead of building a string first.

Comment: true, the issue is that i have multiple threads doing that at the same time...it could literally burn sectors in my ssd

Comment: No it cannot. And multiple MBs are by no definition "massive amounts of lines" any more.

Comment: but what if all the data streams interfere? also its like 1.3+ million lines of text.

Comment: 1 millon lines writes to file in 227ms (with `FileStream` as in my example)